# Remove attributes from a configurable product in Magento

Tags: magento, configuration, attributes, admin, product

Is there any way to remove an attribute from a configurable product once it’s already been created? I tried to remove an attribute from an attribute set but Magento won’t allow you to if it’s already been assigned to a product. The only way I’ve seen to remove attributes from products is directly in the database (**catalog_product_super_attribute** table).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this model to get a collection of the **catalog_product_super_attribute** attribute and proceed to delete the record.

`Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_type_configurable_attribute_collection')`

Be ware, there is an _afterSave method that tries to save the label on another table on Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable_Attribute, which will cause an exception when deleting.